# visual studio - have to build multiple times for changes to take effect

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm having issues with visual studio lately -
When I hit ctrl+F5 (on console application) expecting my project to run, it does not run as expected.
What happens is that for 2 or 3 times, the console window will appear as if it is running normally, but it actually won't display anything inside it.
I need to hit ctrl+F5 multiple times, like 3 or 4, in order for any changes that I've made to take effect.
Plus, it doesn't run any previous code that I have already written, So basically my case is that in order for my code to run, I need to hit ctrl+F5 3 or 4 times anyhow.

Tried to build manually the solution before hand - no good.
Tried my best with playing with the build settings - no good so far.
OS - WIndows 10 Home
VS - 2017 Community

Now the thing is, that the same behavior also occurred with my VS 2015 a few weeks ago.
I reinstalled windows just yesterday, installed fresh new VS 2017, and it still occurs.

[Video demonstration](https://youtu.be/3vgqF58DNoU) 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

OK..
On some try and error. after a few weeks of suffering from it..
Th problem was AVIRA antivirus.
I added an exception for visual studio in it is now fixed.